# C - using global structure

Tags: c

I'm using global structure so I can set/get error or state from everywhere. It was working fine, now I'm in trouble.

structure

```
typedef struct program Program;
struct program
{
    int error;
    int state;
};

// global declarations
Program *program;
```

init

```
void init_memory(void)
{
program = malloc(sizeof(Program));
if(program == NULL)
{
    print_error(E_MEM_ALLOC);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
program->state = S_NONE;
program->error = E_OK;
}
```

here program crashes, when I remove "program->error = ...." program is working fine...i don't know why :/

```
void check_file(char *filename)
{
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

if(file == NULL)
{
    program->error = E_FILE_OPEN;
    return;
}

fclose(file);
}
```

whole program: http://pastebin.com/dwSVQ9x8

Comment: What is `program`? A global variable? You're using a variable with the same name as the structure, which in turn is the same name for a `typedef`'d alias?

Comment: yea I am...anyway, I tried to change variable's name and program still crashes :/

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves he's doing it right actually...
OP: You should extern the global structure in the header file, and just define and actually allocate it in one source file, like: `extern Program* program` in the header, and in source `Program *program;` (not in same file as `check_file` in)

Comment: Might be silly question, but do you actually call `init_memory` before `check_file`?

Comment: @user9000 I'd like to..but this is school project and they want to have it in one source file -_-

Comment: @user694733 Yes, I am

Comment: Problem seems to not be here. Show more code.

Comment: @user9000 No doubt he's doing it right, but it in computer science it is generally good practice to use a name for one thing only. `typedef struct foo { int foo } foo; foo foo;` is valid code, but good luck debugging it. It surely is a cool trick, but not very useful, and anyone reading the code will have a hard time.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves `foo foo;` is not valid.

Comment: @user694733 Sure it is. See http://ideone.com/wo9Vpp - and then read about C namespaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793952/understanding-c-namespaces

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YDe62Vvi
full code here

Comment: @user694733 Sorry, let me rephrase that: it is valid as a local-scope variable. You can't have a global variable named `foo`, since `typedef` shares the same namespace with ordinary identifiers. My example gives the idea that `foo` is a global variable, my fault, sorry. But I can't edit it anymore.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I was just about to post a comment saying exactly the same :) In other words, `typedef struct foo { int foo } foo foo;` is not valid, but `typedef struct foo { int foo } foo; void func(void){ foo foo;}` is.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Well that's what I meant too, just kept my comment too short. Lundin put it a lot better.

Comment: yeah, I kept mine short too :P Sorry for misunderstanding your point.

Comment: I found the cause, from enum it takes only first 4 items, when I want to use 5th, program crashes..any idea why is that?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to hide the code after you have solved the issue, others stumbling upon it in the future may still find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making `program` a pointer seems unnecessary, why not just make it the actual `struct`:

```
Program program = { .error = E_OK, .state = S_NONE };
```

Then you don't need to worry about allocating it (and can indeed remove `init_memory` altogether). Just change access to its members to use `.` instead of `->`, i.e., `program.error = E_FILE_OPEN`.

Comment: (If your compiler doesn't like the designated initializers, you can also initialize it as just `Program program = { E_OK, S_NONE }`.)