# Why does struct have two variable names in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, struct

In the below code why does the struct have two variable names?

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    const rlim_t kStackSize = 64L * 1024L * 1024L;

    struct rlimit rl;    //HERE

    int result = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It has one variable name: `rl`. If this is C++, the `struct` isn't needed, and if this is C, you can change the type so it isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, struct with its tag together is a name, unless it's `typedef`ed.

In C++, you can omit the `struct` keyword.

Comment: Ah so rlimit is a "type" of struct?

Comment: @user997112 In C, `struct rlimit` is a type, `rlimit` alone is just a struct tag.

Answer (score 1):

If this is C, the `struct` is just to tell C that it is in a different namespace.

See: [understanding C namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793952/understanding-c-namespaces)

If this is C+++, then the `struct` is not needed.