# "use of undeclared identifier" when typecasting void pointer to struct pointer

Tags: c, struct

I am new to C and as a (classic) exercise I am trying to implement some operations on linked lists. I haven't gotten very far yet, though... When I am trying to declare and initialize the root node as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct intNode_t {
    int data;
    struct intNode_t* next;
};

int main() {
    struct intNode_t* root = ( intNode_t* ) malloc( sizeof( struct intNode_t ) );
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler (clang) is giving me the error "use of undeclared identifier" at the place where I am trying to typecast the void pointer returned by malloc to a pointer to intNode_t. I realise this is a noob question, but I couldn't find the answer elsewhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: You've spelled the typename `struct intNode_t` twice in your main function. Why are you surprised that the differently spelled name `intNode_t` behaves differently?

Comment: NOTE: `struct intNode_t*` and `intNode_t*` is not the same thing. At least not in C. Just remove that type cast and you will make a lot of people (including yourself) happy.

Comment: Who told you that you should cast the result of `malloc`? Please stop listening to that person immediately, as they will be a major obstacle on your road to learn C.

Comment: You forget the semicolon after struct and before main

Comment: @AlterMann : that was a typo in the question, not in my actual code. Corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for all the comments. @KerrekSB I was told that malloc returns a void pointer and I need a pointer to type intNode_t . why is that bad/wrong?

Comment: @NiH: Because there is an implicit conversion from void pointer to any object pointer. See my answer. It's very dangerous to "be told" stuff, because 90% of programmers are bad programmers, so by randomly listening you have a high chance of copying someone bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names of structs in C occupy a separate namespace from the space of names of fundamental types and typedefs (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793952/understanding-c-namespaces) for details). Therefore, the name of your struct type is `struct intNode_t`; there is no type called `intNode_t`.

You can either always spell out the name as `struct intNode_t`, or you can create a type alias for it. There are many different patterns of this in real code:

**Separate tag name, separate declaration:**

```
typedef struct foo_t_ foo_t;

struct foo_t_ { /* ... */ };
```

This allows you to put the type alias in a header and publish it as an opaque API type without ever revealing the actual type definition.

**Separate tag name, typedef in struct definition:**

```
typedef struct foo_t_ { /* ... */ } foo_t;
```

**Reuse name:**

```
typedef struct foo_t { /* ... */ } foo_t;
```

This style allows users to be careless about spelling `foo_t` or `struct foo_t`.

**Don't name the struct:**

```
typedef struct { /* ... */ } foo_t;
```

---

However, in your code you don't actually need to repeat the name, since [you should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845) and instead rely on the built-in implicit conversion from void pointer to object pointer. You also shouldn't repeat the type that's already known, and use the expression form of `sizeof` instead. So you want:

```
int main()
{
    struct intNode_t* root = malloc(sizeof *root);
}
```

(Also note that `return 0` is implied from `main`.)

Comment: great answer. Thanks for taking the time for such an elaborate explanation!

Comment: @NiH: No problem, though the main credit should go to the two linked questions that do all the hard work.

Answer (score 1):

No need to repeat yourself. If you don't repeat yourself you can make fewer errors.

```
struct intNode_t *root;
root = malloc( sizeof *root );
```

- the cast is not needed; `malloc()` returns a `void*`, which is exchangeable with every (non-function) pointer type.
- there are two syntax variants for sizeof: `sizeof(type)` and `sizeof expression` The first one needs `()`, the second one does not. Most people prefer the second form, because the expression (in your case `*root` ) always will yield the correct type, and thus: size.

And, the definition + assignment above can be combined into a definition + initialiser, all fitting on one line:

```
struct intNode_t *root = malloc( sizeof *root );
```

Comment: Why have a separate declaration and assignment? That just adds noise and removes locality.

Comment: Oops. corrected. 2) because beginners often are confused by the different role of the `*` in declarations/definitions and expressions/initialisers.

Answer (score 0):

Name `intNode_t` was not declared in the program. There is declared structure tag name `intNode_t`.

So you need to write

```
struct intNode_t* root = ( struct intNode_t* ) malloc( sizeof( struct intNode_t ) );
```

Or you could introduce identifier name `intNode_t` the following way

```
typedef struct intNode_t {
    int data;
    struct intNode_t* next;
} intNode_t;
```

In this case you may write

```
struct intNode_t* root = ( intNode_t* ) malloc( sizeof( struct intNode_t ) );
```