# Why does the size of the same identifier differ in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, name-lookup

```
#include <stdio.h>
int T;
int main()
{
    struct T { double x; };  
    printf("%zu", sizeof(T));
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this code in C, the result is `4`, while in C++ it is `8`.

Can someone explain why the difference?

Comment: That's because c and c++ are different languages.

Comment: Well, the language used? It's undefined in any language btw, `%d` expects an `int` and not a `size_t`.

Comment: In one language `T` is a type-name, in the other language it's not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude maybe silly, but this should be an answer ....

Comment: I've made an edit to remove the mismatched `printf` formatter. I don't think it invalidates any of the answers, but if you disagree, do please roll back. Nice quiz question though.

Comment: Why downvotes?? I think, this is not bad question.

Comment: This is an in fact very interesting question. I agree.

Comment: @rsp: It had some UB in it at first, and that together with the multiple language tags were probably grounds for causing offence. Questions like this tend to end up with a positive score though, particularly if the answers are brilliant, which the current top one certainly is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer:** Because they aren't the same identifier, in fact.

In C, structure names and variable names fall into [**different namespaces**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793976/5958455), so in C,

```
sizeof(T) == sizeof(int) // global variable T
sizeof(struct T) == sizeof(struct T) // not the same namespace
```

In C++, however, structure/class names goes into **the same namespace** as variables. [The "nearest" (most local) name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Namespace_scope) is the result of [name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), so now

```
sizeof(T) == sizeof(struct T) // structure T
sizeof(::T) == sizeof(int) // Note the scope resolution operator
```

And therefore the result is 4 and 8, respectively.

In C++, you can get 4 with `sizeof(::T)`. The "double-colon" scope resolution operator forces the compiler to take `T` as the name in external namespace, so `::T` is the variable of type int that you want.

---

In C, (structures/unions/enums) and (variables/functions/typedefs) have separate namespaces, so you can write this without worrying about names conflicting.

```
struct T T;
```

note the parentheses, that structs, unions and enums share one namespace while the other three share another.

If you try to do this in C++, you'll immediately run into problems.

---

I like [hacck's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347461/different-output-in-c-c-with-structure#comment81646791_47347461). He got the point that the fundamental reason is that C and C++ are different languages, despite their similarity.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting different results because C and C++ are different languages.

In C++, when you declare a struct (a special class),

```
struct T { 
    double x; 
};
```

then you can use it as

```
T sobj;  // sobj is an object of type T
```

`T` is a type here.
while in C, `T` is not a type but `struct T` is

```
struct T sobj;
```

Now use `sizeof(T)` or `sizeof(struct T)` in C++ and `sizeof(struct T)` in C and they will give you the size of struct.

Answer (score 3):

In C, the `T` in `struct T` is a *struct tag*. Struct tags reside in a different namespace than variables and types. To get a type in C, you would have to write `struct T`.

`sizeof()` expects either a type or an expression, and a struct tag is neither. You do you however have the variable `T`. A variable name is a valid expression in `sizeof()`.

In C++ however, the `T` in `struct T` is a type name since a struct in C++ is essentially just a class with all members public. Therefore `sizeof(T)` matches the struct type in C++.

---

Notable here is that the `sizeof` operator has two different syntax cases:

`sizeof` *unary-expression*
`sizeof` *( type-name )*

In case of the former, `sizeof` only accepts expressions, but not types. In case of the latter, it excepts either expressions or types. So had you written `sizeof T` instead of `sizeof (T)`, you would have gotten a compiler error in C++, since `T` would then have been a type and not an expression.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in C to refer to the structure you would need to write `struct T` while in C++ since a struct is a public class it can be refered to as just `T`
So both are just taking the most local definition of `T` they have.