# Why does my function only update the struct when I pass it with an & symbol?

Tags: c++, struct

I'm studying coding for some credits in the university, and I was studying and decided to try to make something with structs in C++ to try to understand them better.

I'm trying to make some functions to work with the struct, but they only work if I write & before declaring the arguments, but in the classroom we were told it should not be necessary. My code is the following.

```
struct employee{
   int ID;
   char name;
   double salary;
};

struct empresa{
   char name;
   struct employee employee[];
};


void iterate_trough_employees(struct empresa &empresa, int number_employees){
    for ( int i = 0; i < number_employees; i++){
       empresa.employee[i].ID = i+1;
       printf("\n\n EL ID del empleado es:\t %d \n",empresa.employee[i].ID);
       empresa.employee[i].salary = rand() % 50;
       printf("El salario del empleado es: %.1lf \n", empresa.employee[i].salary);
       }
}

void sort_this(struct empresa &empresa, int number_employees){
   int list_of_ID[number_employees];
   list_of_ID[0]= empresa.employee[4].ID;
   printf("\n%d", empresa.employee[4].ID);
   printf("\n%d", list_of_ID[0]);
   printf("\n%.0lf\n", empresa.employee[6].salary);
}

int main(){
   struct empresa empresa;

   int empleados = 10;
   int orden_salarios[10];
   iterate_trough_employees(empresa, empleados);
   printf("%d", empresa.employee[6].ID);
   sort_this(empresa, empleados);

   return 0;
}
```

I'm mostly interested in the `sort_this` function, which only shows the correct values on screen when I write the K (the code in the function is not related to the title, because I have been trying to figure out the mistake making an easier function).

For those asking, we've been taught to code in C using some C++ elements (such as the pass by reference from C++ or cin/cout) to make it easier, and therefore it may seem to you that the code is not C nor C++.
I'm studying coding for some credits in the university, and I was studying and decided to try to make something with structs in C++ to try to understand them better.

I'm trying to make some functions to work with the struct, but they only work if I write & before declaring the arguments, but in the classroom we were told it should not be necessary. My code is the following.

```
struct employee{
   int ID;
   char name;
   double salary;
};

struct empresa{
   char name;
   struct employee employee[];
};


void iterate_trough_employees(struct empresa &empresa, int number_employees){
    for ( int i = 0; i < number_employees; i++){
       empresa.employee[i].ID = i+1;
       printf("\n\n EL ID del empleado es:\t %d \n",empresa.employee[i].ID);
       empresa.employee[i].salary = rand() % 50;
       printf("El salario del empleado es: %.1lf \n", empresa.employee[i].salary);
       }
}

void sort_this(struct empresa &empresa, int number_employees){
   int list_of_ID[number_employees];
   list_of_ID[0]= empresa.employee[4].ID;
   printf("\n%d", empresa.employee[4].ID);
   printf("\n%d", list_of_ID[0]);
   printf("\n%.0lf\n", empresa.employee[6].salary);
}

int main(){
   struct empresa empresa;

   int empleados = 10;
   int orden_salarios[10];
   iterate_trough_employees(empresa, empleados);
   printf("%d", empresa.employee[6].ID);
   sort_this(empresa, empleados);

   return 0;
}
```

I'm mostly interested in the `sort_this` function, which only shows the correct values on screen when I write the K (the code in the function is not related to the title, because I have been trying to figure out the mistake making an easier function).

For those asking, we've been taught to code in C using some C++ elements (such as the pass by reference from C++ or cin/cout) to make it easier, and therefore it may seem to you that the code is not C nor C++.

Comment: This is C++, not C.

Comment: You pass arguments by reference which doesn't exist in C, and you use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which doesn't exist in C++. So this code is not valid in either language.

Comment: If you don't even know which programming language you are using, there isn't much hope to produce any form of working software...

Comment: Is this valid in C++: `struct empresa empresa;` ? Looks like neither C++, nor C for me.

Comment: Can you explain the effect of "write & before declaring the arguments" ? Does your problem exist for struct parameters you are only reading ? Or only for those which you try to change inside the function?

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps you should [get a good C++ beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over.

Comment: You do not need to provide the `struct` keyword before using a `struct`'s name as a type. `struct` are implicitly type names in c++. This is a relic from c.

Comment: @Gerhardh: That's valid in both.  `struct empresa` names a type, `empresa` names a variable.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, it's valid. It's inherited from c and kept in the language for compatibility. It specifies that the following identifier is a struct type.

Comment: @Gerhardh It's valid in both C and C++, however you'll immediately run into problems in C++ if you do so. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347568/5958455) of mine.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Doesn't C++ automatically define a type with same name when defining a struct? I know that it is valid in C.

Comment: FWIW, "*we've been taught to code in c using some c++ elements*" - tell your teacher that this is a terrible way to learn, as you'll end up learning neither language properly.  Indeed, the symptoms you're seeing relate to the `&`, which is a C++ feature.

Comment: @Gerhardh - It's retained in C++ as a vestigial back-compatibility thing.

Comment: Given that the declaration is `struct empresa empresa` and no custom allocation, `empresa` does not contain space for even a single employee. Everything beyond that is accessing unallocated memory.

Comment: What is **certain** is that this code **isn't** C or any extension, because of the `&` pass-by-reference.

Comment: _"[I] decided to try to make something with structs in C++ to try to understand them better."_ Why didn't you first try to understand the basic syntax of the language, like pointers, references, values, and the difference between them, particularly regarding functions? There's no point in coding custom structs and functions if you don't get grok the fundamentals of the language. It doesn't make for a useful question, anyway, as it demonstrates a lack of basic research before posting. You shouldn't learn programming by trial and error, and we shouldn't help you to do so.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a function with `void foo(struct bar x)` and you call it with `foo(y)`, the compiler makes a copy of `y` and assigns that copy to `x`. Then changing the copy `x` inside the function has no effect on the original `y`.

When you declare a function with `void foo(struct bar *x)` and you call it with `foo(&y)`, the compiler takes the address of `y` and assigns that value to `x`. Then `x` is a copy of the address, but you use `*x` or `x->member` inside the function, and these refer to the object at the address. Since the address points to the original object `y`, changing `*x` and `x->member` change the original object `y`.

When you declare a function with `void foo(struct bar &x)` and you call it with `foo(y)`, the compiler takes the address of `y` and passes that to the function. When compiling the function, the compiler knows `x` is supposed to be a reference, not a pointer to or a copy of the original object. So, wherever `x` is used in the function, the compiler uses the address it was passed to refer to the original object. So changes to `x` in the function are changes to the original object. Where you write `x.member = something;`, the compiler uses the address that was passed for `x` to change the value of `member` in the original object `y`. This feature is only in C++; it is not in C.

The first is called pass by value.

The third is called pass by reference.

The second is equivalent to pass by reference except that it is manual instead of automatic; you explicitly pass a pointer and must manually write out the `*x` or `x->member` instead of `x` or `x.member`.

---

A note about `struct empresa empresa;` in `main`. Your `struct empresa` is defined with `struct employee employee[];`. This is a flexible array member, and defining an object of that type in this way does not allocate any storage for elements of the array. The proper way to use it is allocate storage for the base structure (`sizeof(struct empresa)`) plus as many elements as you want (`+ empleados * sizeof(struct employee)`). To do this, you will have to use `malloc` or a related function.

Flexible array members are an extension supported by some C++ implementations. They are not a standard part of the language.

Comment: In your third paragraph " the compiler takes the address of y and passes that to the function" is a possible implementation detail. The actual language specification is that `y` is passed to the function by reference

Comment: @M.M: View it as a description of the abstract model, subject to implementation in any way the compiler chooses.