# Do struct tags, union tags and enum tags have separate namespaces?

Tags: c, namespaces, name-lookup

[schot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793976/5958455) is a good one. He claimed that

> - Tags (names of structures, unions and enumerations).

I think that the tags for structures, unions and enumerations have different namespaces, so that this code is completely fine:

```
// In the same scope
struct T {};
union T {};
enum T {};
```

But inferring from the quotation above, it looks like all tags share the same namespace. Is the answer not clear enough or am I wrong?

Comment: For what it's worth, `gcc` gives a hard error for this, so I would say struct, union, and enum tags are all part of the same tag namespace.  I think they *could* be made to occupy independent namespaces, but apparently they do not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

All the tags share the same namespace. So you are not allowed to have:

```
struct T {...};
union T {...};
enum T {...};
```

[C11 draft N1570, 6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3) explicitly add s footnote.

> 32) There is **only one name space for tags** even though three are possible.

Comment: To clarify: Three are possible. Never at once. C won't accept multiple at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not have separate namespaces. There is only one namespace for tags. This means

```
struct TS{};
union TU{};
int TS, TU;
```

is valid while

```
struct T{};
union T{};
```

is not. Two declarations of `T` are in the same namespace.

Comment: @iBug;  Now your question edit make my answer wrong. Editing it.

Comment: Well, that's just what I originally indented to ask. Otherwise I wouldn't have left ellipses in braces.

Comment: @iBug; Empty braces is in fact valid syntax while ellipses inside bracket are not. That's why I removed it. One can compile and test the code to verify the answer.

Comment: Good. I followed you up.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question:

Tag names: all identifiers declared as names of `structs`, `unions` and enumerated types. Note that all three kinds of tags share one name space.

Just quoting this from [reference guide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/name_space).

> At the point of lookup, the name space of an identifier is determined by the manner in which it is used:
>
> - identifier that follows the keyword `struct`, `union`, or `enum` is looked up in the tag name space.