# What is the purpose of typedef of an enum in C Language?

Tags: c, struct, enums, typedef

I ran into the following code and I'm trying to understand how this code works and the reason it was used.

```
enum eKeyEvent
{
    eNoEvent = 0,
    eKeyChanged
};
 
typedef enum eKeyEvent eKeyEvent_t;
 
typedef struct {
    unsigned int ButtonMatrix;
    unsigned int ChangedMask;
}
 KeypadEvent_t;
 
static unsigned int  KP_Sample;
static unsigned int  KP_Last;
static unsigned int  KP_Changed;
static unsigned int  KP_Stable;
static unsigned char KP_DebounceCounter;
```

This code was given as an example for a matrix keypad scan, but I guess it was assumed everyone would understand.  If I can understand how this works I will understand the rest of the code.

I have looked up the data types (pardon my lack of using the correct terminology here; I'm self taught), but I'm still confused about this line: typedef enum eKeyEvent eKeyEvent_t;  The struct puzzles me probably because I don't understand the typedef enum.

Comment: It just means “instead of having to write `enum eKeyEvent` every time I can now write `eKeyEvent_t` as the type”. So in code you’d normally write `enum eKeyEvent variable;` and now it can be `eKeyEvent_t variable;`. Convenience thing only.

Comment: [C has distinct namespaces for types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793952/understanding-c-namespaces), and using `typedef` is a half-century-old technique to bring a type-name into the default namespace. It's a wart in C's design that cannot be smoothed-over.

Comment: What is unclear? Don't you know what typedef does?

Comment: I have another more general question. What is the purpose of `enum`s in C?

Comment: @0___________ : They work better than macros for constant ints. (Especially in header files.)

Comment: @Joshua elaborate. Provide any evidence that they are better. Explain what is better?

Comment: @0___________: 1) They show up in debugger symbol files. 2) They are normal symbols and don't blow up when used as names inside structs or as local declarations.

Comment: @Joshua https://godbolt.org/z/oYvd6fc1z not very good

Comment: @Joshua this one is even better: https://godbolt.org/z/4s1fW9bos or https://godbolt.org/z/ef98ndoTv - ups

Comment: @Joshua - so where is the superiority? It is extremely error prone to use enums instead of `defines`

Comment: @0___________: In your first example, enums are ints not unsigned longs. I'm disappointed you didn't get a warning on `bar = ...ULL;` In your second example, that's why I think they're good. If you think it's bad that's where we have a difference of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enum`, `struct` and `union` specifically have their own little (blunt) type naming mechanism known as "tags". In `enum eKeyEvent` the  `eKeyEvent` is a tag and you could have similarly named the struct with a tag `struct KeypadEvent_t` etc.

In this case the keyword + tag, `enum eKeyEvent`, makes up a type. Meaning that each time you want to declare a variable of that type, you must type out:

```c
enum eKeyEvent my_event;
```

The `typedef` eliminates this need and with a `typedef` you just have to type:

```c
eKeyEvent_t my_event;
```

Which one to use is considered a matter of style. The latter form is the by far most common and makes your custom types behave similarly to other default types.

It would perhaps be more common to write the `typedef` together with the `enum` declaration as was done with your struct. This is 100% equivalent:

```c
typedef enum eKeyEvent  // we don't even need the tag name here
{
    eNoEvent = 0,
    eKeyChanged
} eKeyEvent_t;
```

---

To make things more confusing, tags exist in their own unique namespace, whereas `typedef` name types end up in the normal identifier namespace along with variable and function names etc. So this is also legit code:

```c
typedef struct KeypadEvent_t { // this is a struct tag
    unsigned int ButtonMatrix;
    unsigned int ChangedMask;
} KeypadEvent_t;  // this is a type name identifier
```

And now we may refer to this struct either as `struct KeypadEvent_t` (tag) or `KeypadEvent_t` (typedef name identifier) and it will mean the same struct. And the two forms are 100% compatible with each other.

---

Tags aren't an entirely superfluous feature though, we can use them for self-referencing structs:

```c
typedef struct node
{
  /* stuff here */
  struct node* next;
} node_t;
```

This is a common way to define nodes in a linked list. Thanks to the tag we can self-reference the struct before we are even done with the declaration. But from here on we can just refer to it as `node_t` and treat `next` as a `node_t*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum eKeyEvent
{
    eNoEvent = 0,
    eKeyChanged
};
 
typedef enum eKeyEvent eKeyEvent_t;
```

I do not know why the author slit it into two declarations. In this context, there is no reason for that.

It can be declared as:

```
typdef enum eKeyEvent
{
    eNoEvent = 0,
    eKeyChanged
}eKeyEvent_t;
```

or without the tag:

```
typedef enum 
{
    eNoEvent = 0,
    eKeyChanged
}eKeyEvent_t;
```

Split declarations using tags make sense if it is a "forward declaration" to use the type as "incomplete type"

```
typedef enum eKeyEvent eKeyEvent_t;

struct foo
{
    eKeyEvent_t *x;
};


struct foo y; 

int bar(eKeyEvent_t *x)
{
    return !!x;
}
```

---

Another question is: what is the purpose of the `enum` types in C as objects having enum type can hold other values than defined in the enum declaration?