# Each .h file requires a struct defined in the other? (C)

Tags: c

I've got two header files, each requiring a type defined in the other. When I try to compile, I get an error regarding an unknown type name. (If I provide only struct declarations and not definitions, I get an incomplete-types error.) What's a solution that will let me share these structs properly?

Right now, my code looks rather like the following (just imagine the `#ifndef` preprocessor directives etc.):

```
<headerA.h>

#include "headerB.h"
typedef struct { 
  mytypeB myB;
} mytypeA;

<headerB.h>

#include "headerA.h"
typedef struct {} mytypeB;
void foo( mytypeA * myA);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should forward-declare the `struct mytypeA` instead of including `headerA.h`:

Inside headerB.h:

```
struct mytypeA; // <<<--- Forward declaration

void foo(struct mytypeA* myA);
```

This works because you are not using the actual `mytypeA`, only a pointer to it. You cannot pull the same trick with `headerA`, because `mytypeA` includes the actual `mytypeB`.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward declare a structure without needing to define the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

These SO questions might help you since it is related to your question.

[undefined C struct forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621356/undefined-c-struct-forward-declaration)

[How to declare a structure in a header that is to be used by multiple files in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228684/how-to-declare-a-structure-in-a-header-that-is-to-be-used-by-multiple-files-in-c)